# How do i find the number of times x=x+1 is executed in terms of N?

Tags: time-complexity, discrete-mathematics

im also having trouble finding omega(), and theta() as appropriate

```
    x=0;
    for k=1 to n
     for j=1 to n-k
      X=X+1;
```

Comment: What are omega() and theta()?

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop is n-1 + n-2 + n-3 ... + 1 + 0.  Use [this tutorial](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/series4.htm) on calculating the sum of an arithmetic series to find the solution.  The outer loop is obviously just "n."

This will be the big-theta.  The big-oh will be the same as big-theta when you pull off everything but the first term and remove the multiplier, e.g. Theta(2*log(n) + 5) becomes O(log(n)).  Omega is the same as big-Oh in this case, because the best case and worst case are identical; or you can cheat and say that big-Omega is constant time, because the big-Omega of EVERY function is constant time.

Comment: Much prefer your answer to mine. Nice pointer without giving the answer away. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

First, look at your boundaries. k=1 and k=n.

For k=1, the inside loop is executed (n-1) times.
For k=n the inside loop is execured (0) times.

So, 0 + 1 + ... + (n-1)  is an arithmetic sum => (n-1)(n)/2 times.

Now, test it on a few small values :)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is like this : 
 n-1 + n -2 + n -3 + ... = n*n - (1+2+3+ ... + n) = n^2 - n(n-1)/2